# Can't find line causing Deprecation warning

Tags: ember.js

My Rails/Ember app is currently using ember version 1.5.1. I want to bring it to the last version of Ember and I'm doing so by updating one version at a time so I can get all deprecation warnings and fix them before moving on. When I try to go from version 1.6.1 to version 1.7.1 I get the following deprecation warning but I can't find anywhere in my app where I use then on an instance of Application.

Do you have any tips on how can I investigate and find where this use of then is happening? The provided stack trace is not being of any use for me.

```
DEPRECATION: Do not use `.then` on an instance of Ember.Application.  Please use the `.ready` hook instead.
    at Namespace.extend.then (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:2861:15)
    at apply (http://`localhost:3000`/assets/ember.js?body=1:18384:27)
    at superWrapper [as then] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:17961:15)
    at tryThen (http://loDEPRECATION: Do not use `.then` on an instance of Ember.Application.  Please use the `.ready` hook instead.
    at Namespace.extend.then (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:2861:15)
    at apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:18384:27)
    at superWrapper [as then] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:17961:15)
    at tryThen (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:45661:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:45670:21
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:29072:9
    at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:635:18)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:685:15)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:148:27)calhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:45661:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:45670:21
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:29072:9
    at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:635:18)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:685:15)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:148:27)
```

Comment: Are you doing something funky like `wait(app)` or `Ember.run(app)`? I'm guessing it's a problem with with some async logic + the run loop. Otherwise, just start triaging (comment out all of the app, see what parts you can get to load, narrow it down).

Comment: Do you have any Ember-specific addons or libraries that you're using? If so, would you mind posting the names and versions?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the [debugging page](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/debugging/):

```
Ember.run.backburner.DEBUG = true;
```

Hopefully it gives you the full backtrace to the code that's causing the issue.